# How to show edit text field on HTML page programmatically?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following task: there are a simple table from mysql database:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<?php
    mysql_connect('url','user','') or die('Connect');
    mysql_select_db('jquery_test') or die('Db');
    $query=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM labels');
    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$data['id'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$data['label'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$data['english'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This code show a simple talbe. I need to make the following feature: when the user moves the cursor to $data['english'] field then it must appear the text field for editing and "Save" button; when the cursor leaves this word then the field must dissapear. There is a fantastic example what I mean: http://translate.uservoice.com/sets/51-end-user-ru/translations?filter=missing. Please, help me, I know only HTML/PHP and don't know how can I do this task. It will be very good to use JQuery for it.

Comment: I can't make up my mind what's going on here; fair or foul, student or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html) jquery plugin to make editable labels and use it on `.mouseover()` and  `.mouseleave()` functions.